# Assigning domain names to different URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, dns

I have created a site builder application, where site visitors can build their websites on their own using my site. Currently, each site url is like this:

```
www.sitebuilder.com/sites/site_id=18
```

What I want is to enable each user to have a real domain for their site. For example, if the user with `site_id=18` wants a new domain name as:

```
www.newdomain.com
```

Then `www.newdomain.com` should show the content of `www.sitebuilder.com/sites/site_id=18`

But it should not be done by forwarding. Any ideas on how to do it ?

Comment: I think there are plenty of hosts (MediaTemple, for example) that offer this as a part of their service. [ExpressionEngine Multi-Site Manager](http://expressionengine.com/downloads/details/multiple_site_manager/) also solves this problem, potentially.

Answer (score 1):

The A records for `www.newdomain.com` and (probably) `newdomain.com` would need to be pointed your server (if you don't know this already/know what this means, I think it's important you do at least a little reading on how [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) works). Then you have two options:

- Arguably the better and more commonly used approach is to use virtual hosting on your web server (with something like Apache's [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html)), and configure the server in such a way that when it receives a request for a given domain, it serves the correct files - from the look of the way your URL scheme currently works, this would be a less than simple task without drastically changing your architecture, and you would need to know what you were doing.
- You can check the domain that was used to access the site from within PHP (using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`), and serve the correct files based on this. This would probably be simpler to set up, but I personally would consider it less sustainable in the long term - this is my personal opinion and YMMV, it is a subject that could probably be debated for hours (although SO is not the place for that debate).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply .

mod_vhost_alias can only be used if I am serving each file from a separate directory . 

The issue is that each file is not being server from a different directory , rather it is being grabbed from database using it's id which is passed in parameters : site_id=18  , both solutions you recommended will not serve the purpose of mapping domain to url , instead they map domain to directory

Comment: Point 2 will allow you to do this, although point 1 will not - that's what I meant by `this would be a less than simple task without drastically changing your architecture`. You can do it with point 2 though - you just use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to identify the site, instead of `$_GET['site_id']` - I presume `site_id` is a database index? So just add an extra field(s) to that table, with the domain(s) that are used to access the site, and use something like:

Comment: `if (isset($_GET['site_id'])) {$siteId = $_GET['site_id'];} else {$siteId = mysql_query("SELECT side_id FROM sites WHERE domain_alias = '{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}'"); $siteId = mysql_fetch_array($siteId); $siteId = $siteId['site_id'];}`

Comment: Now `$siteId` contains the index, retrieved based on the domain that was used to access the site.

Comment: so basically what can be done is 

a) Change the A record of the domain to point to our server : let's say 127.0.0.1 

b) This server will have a default index file , which will check for the domain name or subdomain . 

c) Depending on domain , it will deliver the content .

Comment: That's the idea - presumably exactly like you have now, only instead of using `?site_id=18` to identify the site that should be served, use the above code (or something like it) to get the site id from the database, based on the domain used to access it. The above code allows you use both methods to access the site.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what kind of hosting setup you have. Anytime I've seen this (where you want a domain mapped directly to a path and NOT use a redirect of any kind) that needs to be handled by the backend of the host usually through manual adjustment of the settings.

For example, how does a user even get their own URL? Obviously they won't go to GoDaddy and buy their own – you probably offer it as a service and take care of the registrar stuff on your own.

Hate to say it, but you may just have to manually map a domain to the correct folder on the server space whenever a user purchases one. I'm sure that domain process isn't 100% automated currently, so what's an extra 5 minutes of work here and there? Just setup a script that'll shoot you an email when someone pays for a domain that reminds you to make the necessary backend changes. And then tell a user and change will take 24-48 hours to implement initially.